# Finding 2nd to last date with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to find the 2nd to last date using the below query to get all unique dates.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CAST(Entrydatetime AS DATE)
FROM   [table_name]
```

This returns

```
2017-11-15
2017-11-16
2017-11-17
2017-11-20
```

The [table_name] contains many rows, many that are all on the same dates listed above. (200 records with '2017-11-20' and 180 with '2017-11-17' etc..)

So is there a way to just grab the 2nd to last item given from the above query?

If this were an array I could do something like '$array[-2]'

So in this instance it would pull 2017-11-17.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? MySQL? SQL Server? ...

Comment: ANSI SQL `... ORDER BY datecolmnalias DESC OFFSET 2 FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY`

Comment: `select max(Entrydatetime) from t where Entrydatetime < (select max(Entrydatetime) from t)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using SQL Server, you can use the following query:

```
with cte as
(
select DISTINCT Convert(Date,Entrydatetime) ,
ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Convert(Date,Entrydatetime) DESC) as rn
from [table name]
) 
select * from cte where rn=2
```

Or you can do it another way

```
SELECT MAX(Convert(Date,Entrydatetime)) 
FROM [table name] 
WHERE Convert(Date,Entrydatetime) < (SELECT MAX(Convert(Date,Entrydatetime) ) FROM [table name])
```

Comment: Sorry should have been a bit more descriptive. This is for MSSQL. There are a lot of rows in the table, some such as 2017-11-20 09:00:00, 2017-11-20 12:00:00 etc...so the answer provided only brings up the 2nd record in the table (which isnt 2017-11-17). Is there a way to just grab the 2nd to last number off the inital query in my question? Thanks again for the help

Comment: @ertuu85 try using `SUBSTRING(Entrydatetime,1,10)` instead of ENtrydatetime

Comment: @ertuu85 or try using `Convert(Date,Entrydatetime)` instead of `CAST9Entrydatetime as DATE)` to remove time from datetime values

Comment: @ertuu85 i provided another way, check out my answer

Comment: Thats got it! Thanks!

Comment: Sorry if I'm wrong- is the order by doing this by `DISTINCT Entrydatetime`?  I get the same value `2017-11-20` for rn = 1 and rn = 2.  For these values for example: `INSERT INTO @tablename VALUES ('2017-11-15 12:00:00'), ('2017-11-16 12:00:00'), ('2017-11-17 12:00:00'), ('2017-11-20 12:00:00'), ('2017-11-20 13:00:00')`

Comment: Use `convert(date, entrydatetime)` instead of `Entrydatetime` to remove the time from dates

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` to rank your dates:

```
select dt
from
(
  select distinct 
    cast(entrydatetime as date) as dt,
    row_number() over (order by cast(entrydatetime as date) desc) as rn
  from table_name
) ranked
where rn = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using a CTE.  I think the DISTINCT EntryDate has to be taken- cast to date to remove time- then the rownumber applied.  Notice I am using two different times for 2017-11-20, 12:00:00 and 13:00:00.  The ORDER BY cannot do this correctly if you have `DISTINCT` in the select... this *requires* a subquery.

```
DECLARE @tablename TABLE (Entrydatetime datetime)
INSERT INTO @tablename VALUES ('2017-11-15 12:00:00')
                             ,('2017-11-16 12:00:00')
                             ,('2017-11-17 12:00:00')
                             ,('2017-11-20 12:00:00')
                             ,('2017-11-20 13:00:00')
;
WITH cte AS
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY EntryDate DESC) [theOrder]
      ,dT.EntryDate
  FROM (
         SELECT DISTINCT CAST(Entrydatetime as date) AS EntryDate
           FROM @tablename
       ) AS dT
)

SELECT cte.EntryDate FROM cte WHERE theOrder = 2
```

Gives output:

```
EntryDate
2017-11-17
```